# Chaining promises doesn't pass data from one .then to the next

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, mocha.js

I am trying to chain promises in a mocha test but it seems like data isn't passed from one .then to the next.

I am trying to test a function that would update a row in a database. Then I want to query that row to see if the change has been applied.

My test:

```
    it("should update the status of an appointment", function(done) {
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        updateStatus(testDb, 3, "In Progress", function(err) {
          if (err) reject(err);
          resolve();
        });
      })
        .then(() => {
          new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            getOneAppointment(testDb, 3, function(err, appt) {
              if (err) reject(err);
              resolve(appt);
            });
          });
        })
        .then(appt => {
          console.log(appt);
          expect(appt).deep.equal(updatedResponse);
          done();
        })
        .catch(err => {
          done(err);
        });
    });
```

The console.log in the second .then prints out as undefined.

Comment: Return your new promises

Comment: it's useful to know, that without any `return` statement a function has an *implied* `return undefined` ... it's also useful to know that the short version of arrow function such as ... `arg => blah()` is equivalent to `arg => { return blah();}` ... so at least one of the places above you could remove some `{}` rather than add `return`

Comment: @Trevor it works but can you explain why I don't need to return the first promise?

Comment: In theory you should return it to something. It's not great to use the new keyword and not store the value to something. But your first promise doesn't resolve to a value, so returning it would give undefined, same as not returning it. As a habit, i usually return true for success and false for fail on any promise that doesn't have a real return value.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, you should return your new Promise. Below is a mock example that illustrates Promise chaining:

```js
new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {
    console.log("Should update the status of an appopintment");
    resolve( { status: 1 } );
} )
.then( function ( statusResult ) {
    return new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {
        console.log("updateStatus");
        resolve( { update: 2 } );
    } );
} )
.then( function ( updateResult) {
    return new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {
        console.log("getOneAppointment");
        resolve( { appointment: 3 } );
    } );
} )
.then( function( appointmentResult ) {
    return new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {
        console.log("updatedResponse");
        resolve( { update: 4 } );
    } );
} )
.then( function( updateResult ) {
    console.log("Done");
} )
```

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work because the code didn't specify `return` for the second `then`. We need to specify `return` because we want to use `then` afterward.

```js
it("should update the status of an appointment", function(done) {
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    updateStatus(testDb, 3, "In Progress", function(err) {
      if (err) reject(err);
      resolve();
    });
  })
    .then(() => {
      // specify `return` here
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        getOneAppointment(testDb, 3, function(err, appt) {
          if (err) reject(err);
          resolve(appt);
        });
      });
    })
    .then(appt => { // so we can proceed with this
      console.log(appt);
      expect(appt).deep.equal(updatedResponse);
      done();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      done(err);
    });
});
```

You don't need to specify `return` at the **first promise** because you use `done` (callback) here. If you add `return`, it will show you error

```
Error: Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback *or* return a Promise; not both.
```

Mocha literally can support promise (no need to specify `done` as callback). Here is the alternative without `done` which I think cleaner:

```js
it("should update the status of an appointment", function() { // remove done
  // add return
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    updateStatus(testDb, 3, "In Progress", function(err) {
      if (err) reject(err);
      resolve();
    });
  })
    .then(() => {
      // specify `return` here
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        getOneAppointment(testDb, 3, function(err, appt) {
          if (err) reject(err);
          resolve(appt);
        });
      });
    })
    .then(appt => { // so we can proceed with this
      console.log(appt);
      expect(appt).deep.equal(updatedResponse);
      // remove done()
    });
});
```

References:

- https://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises

Hope it helps